# Basic matplotlib line chart with 2 dimensions: How to plot visits by date and device?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am a Python beginner and trying to plot a dataframe using pyplot. I've pulled some data from BigQuery on visits in the last 7 days, by device, it looks like this:

```
        date   device  visits
0   20180124   mobile  115702
1   20180125   mobile  105954
2   20180129   mobile  113124
3   20180127   mobile  127296
4   20180128   mobile  154099
5   20180126   mobile  103966
6   20180130   mobile  104010
7   20180130   tablet   19014
8   20180129   tablet   21420
...
```

I'd like to plot visits per day into a line chart, with a line for each device, my current code below is generating a chart with a single line that looks like scrambled spaghetti - how can I tell pyplot how to display the data?

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
from pandas.io import gbq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

pkey='xxx.json'
project_id = "xxx"

query = """
    #standardSQL
    SELECT date,
    device.devicecategory AS device,
    SUM(totals.visits) AS visits
    FROM `xxx.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
    WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between 
    DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 3 day) and
    DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)
    GROUP BY date, device
    """

results = gbq.read_gbq(query, project_id=project_id, dialect='standard', private_key=pkey)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)

df.sort_values(by='date', ascending=True)
fdate = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%Y%m%d")

print(df)

plt.plot(fdate, df['visits'])
plt.ylabel('Sessions')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post an image of the plot you are getting?

Comment: Sure, have added this to my question.

Comment: First thing is you need to sort your data. See [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). For plotting two lines you may `groupby` your dataframe by the device column.

Comment: You should also convert your date into a datetime object with pandas doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, where should this sit in my code? I've placed `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)` before the dataframe is printed by the results are unchanged?

Comment: To notify people in a comment use the @ sign - otherwise they will not see your comment. If the datetime format cannot be infered, you need to specify it directy `format="%y%m%d"`,

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest could you show me an example of where this should sit in the code in relation to where the dataframe is created - is any line after okay?

Comment: I have updated my code block in question with my latest additions, which seem to have made no difference.

Comment: You still did not sort the values that you plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest where do I add `df.sort_values(by='date', ascending=True)` in order to action this? Is this line of code correct, but in the wrong position, or entirely wrong?

Comment: I guess you just forgot to assign it to the dataframe, `df = df.sort_values(..)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Aha, got it! And how about grouping by device so I can show one line per device type?